# Bootstrap grid adding has margin on left and right?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm building an Application in Angular and am trying to use bootstrap col to space & format my page with ease except I appear to have some margin on my page around the element which I've applied col-lg-12 surely shouldn't it fit the entire span of the page?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="header">Turtle</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrpc9a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html

It's literally a barebones application at the moment but I'm a little befuddled as to why this is happening.

Comment: bootstraps `container` class has margin by default. remove that class if you don't want margin.

Comment: Thanks Taylor, I knew it would be something simply just wasn't sure where to look, & sorry isherwood, I personally thought that having a link to my wrapper markup would have been sufficient.

Comment: Are you familiar with using your browser's document inspector to examine where padding and margin occur, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep the container as a good organizational approach, but switch to `.container-fluid` and apply this in your custom stylesheet:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
}
```

You could also add another class to be more granular:

```
.container-fluid.full-width {
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aernuc?file=src/app/header/header.component.css)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div with the container class.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#containers